# Can work out how to redirect capture page to affiliate username

Tags: php, redirect, echo

```
    <?php header('Location: http://potttmatrix.biz/?r=;echo $r;echo'); 
?>
```

That is what im trying at the min I want the page to redirect to the referring persons link they were first at on the referral page.

Comment: why didnt you put the answer then if you knew it?? I am still training and got stuck lol

Comment: Because this is so basic stuff that even if you have answer for this you will stuck to next code block if you are not reading and learning the basics first :)

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
header("Location: http://potttmatrix.biz/?r=$r");
```

or

```
header('Location: http://potttmatrix.biz/?r='.$r);
```

Your code was a bit confusing, but I am assuming that you are trying to append a variable to a string.

Edit, as suggested by Chris Hayes:

In short, single quotes will take the value of the string as a literal value, while double quotes will "parse" your variable. Therefore, with single quotes you need to append the variable from the outside of the string, where with double quotes you can just include the variable in the string and it's value will be shown instead.

Comment: it didnt work tried them both i was using the same command I knew I was doing wrong hence I was asked for help is should redirect to http://potttmatrix.biz?r=mikesherratt and the mikesherratt is missing do I need something on the page they came from??

Comment: I think you have some missing information in your question.
If your $r variable has "mikesherratt" as a value, then yes, it should redirect you to that page! It seems to me that your problem comes from way earlier in your script, and your $r variable is empty!

Comment: +1 but I'd suggest adding a note about the difference between `'` and `"` and variable interpolation in strings, as it would be very easy to miss the difference between your strings here.